# Insert text into a password field from form application

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a Windows form application where I want to automate some tasks. I'm have a problem when it comes to password fields.

My problem is when I press the submit button it says incorrect username/password. When I pass my text into the text fields like:

> Username: hey
>
> Password: hey

(So in the password field it's still plain text but it should have changed to ●●●)

I guess it's becuase I set the value, and that's why it only works with the username.

I have also tried:

```
element.InnerText = "hey";
```

Does anyone know how I can insert a valid password "text" like ●●● insert of plain text.

I don't know if it has any significance but there is also some javascript on the textfield (on the site I'm trying to login at). 
Another thing is when i inspect the source I can see that the passwords field type="text"?

I have tried other automation software and I can see that they can't insert into the password field either. So perhaps there is some kind of blockage here?

I hope I make myself clear, else I would gladly explain in more details.

And I must say I have almost searched the entire web without any luck! :p

Thanks

**Solved**

The problem was that there was a textbox on top of the password field. I suddenly saw that after I looked in the source code again!

Comment: Is this a Web Forms or MVC application? please add more tags.

Comment: It is a Windows Forms / WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) application

Comment: I have actually solved the problem, on my own now! The problem was that there was a textbox on top of the other one. I guess they have made that becuase they wanted a plain text like: password. Thanks for your time guys!

Comment: Windows Forms/WPF Application?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that there was a textbox on top of the password field. I suddenly saw that after I looked in the source code again!

The thing there confused me was because I couldn't see any there were any text inserted. lol

Answer (score 0):

On the textbox on witch you type the password change the textbox.PasswordChar proporty to ●

```
textbox1.PasswordChar = '●';
```